# How to get bash like environment variable value?

Tags: tcl

There is a string like this: `set mystring "$ENV_NAME/c/a/b/c"`

How to get the full path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the full path, you will need to use `file join`. To get to the environment variable, you will need to access the global `env` array:

```
set fullPath [file join $env(ENV_NAME) c a b c]
```

If `ENV_NAME=/usr/bin`, then the above will return `fullPath` as `/usr/bin/c/a/b/c`. You will get similar results in Windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your question is not very clear.

You say that you have the string `set mystring "$ENV_NAME/c/a/b/c"`, which could either mean that this is some user supplied input, or it could be part of your program/Tcl script.

- If this is indeed user supplied input, I suggest you use `eval`:

  ```
  proc substEnv {input} {
      set __ENV [array get ::env]
      dict with __ENV {}
      eval $input
  }
  puts [substEnv {set mystring "$ENV_NAME/c/a/b/c"}]
  ```

  If you can trust the user, this is fine, otherwise I suggest using a [safe interpreter](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/interp.htm). Note that a safe interpreter does not have access to the `::env` array, so you have to pass the contents of it to the safe interpreter.
- But if this is part of your program, I suggest you use `file join` instead

  ```
  set path [file join $::env(ENV_NAME) c a b c]
  ```

  `file join` deals with things like `$::env(ENV_NAME)` is the root directory (`/` on *nix or `C:\` on windows, which both end with the path separator as special case)

Comment: You'd be better off with `set __ENV [array get ::env];dict with __ENV {return [subst -nobackslashes -nocommands $input]}`

Comment: Not exactly. He wants the path, which is IMHO only the last part. Sure, `subst [lindex $input end]` could do the same.